# How to use multiple alias names in keytool genkeypair command?

Tags: server, command, alias, keytool

Can I use something like:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore node1.keystore -alias **name1,name2,name3** \
-dname "CN=node1.example.com,O=Hadoop" -keyalg RSA \
-keysize 2048 -storepass changeme -keypass changeme
```

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve